# Says my return expression cannot be resolved to a type; trying to interleave arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to interleave two arrays so that it goes {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. How can I do this, I keep getting error saying that my return variable cannot be resolved to a type.

```
package osu.cse1223;

public class Lab10b2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1= {1,3,5,7};
        int [] array2= {2,4,5,8};
        int n1=(array1.length)/(array2.length);
        int n2=(array2.length)/(array1.length);
        int [] array3=new int[n1+n2];
        int [] result=mergearrays(array1,array2,n1,n2);
    }
    private static int[] mergearrays(int [] a1,int [] a2,int[] a3, int n1, int n2, int n3) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        while (i<n1&&j<n2) {
            if(a1[i]<a2[j])
                a3[k++]=a1[i++];
            else 
                a3[k++]=a2[j++];

        }
        while (i<n1) {
            a3[k++]=a1[i++];
        }
        while (j<n2) {
            a3[k++]=a1[i++];
        }
        return a3[];
    }
}
```

Comment: `return a3[];` doesn't make sense. Did you mean to state, `return a3;`?

Comment: `return a3[];` <-- this is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

As I know, You do not have to return a3, which is array3 because array in Java is a reference.
If you return: please make sure:

```
return a3;
```

do not

```
return a3[];
```

I do not why you have n1, n2 in there. 
My idea is

1. join them since two arrays are already sorted. 
   2.Find the comment between them, then assign one number to array3.

Below is my code. I hope it can help you.

```
public class asdad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1= {1,3,5,7};
        int [] array2= {2,4,5,8};
        /*Find how many numbers repeat in both arrays*/
        int repeatedNumber=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
            if(array1[i]==array2[i]) repeatedNumber++;
        }
        /*declare and assign a fix size for the array3*/
        int [] array3=new int[array1.length+array2.length-repeatedNumber];
        /*Call the function to do the job which is merge 2 arrays in asc order*/
        mergearrays(array1,array2,array3);

        /*Testing the array3*/
        for(int i=0;i<array3.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(array3[i]);
        }

    }
    private static void mergearrays(int [] a1,int [] a2, int[]a3) {
        int k=0;

        for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
            // Placing this condition first to ensure the repeating number will have one position in the a3
            if(a1[i]==a2[i]) {
                a3[k++]=a1[i];
            }else {
                if(i<a1.length) a3[k++]=a1[i];
                if(i<a2.length) a3[k++]=a2[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
```